# Reports & Record Types

Tags: record-type

We are just incorporating record types in our environment. We are using record types to divide the different divisions within the company. One user was a Record type 1 user but now is being moved to work in the new division that we just created a record type 2 for. I have assigned him the record type 2 default to his profile and manually removed his name from all the shared reports.

I also created sharing rules to only allow certain sharing of records not between divisions.
Problem I can't seem to figure out is how is he still able to see the folders for all the reports and report names? When he runs the report it returns no records, which is good, but I want to remove all the folders and reports from his and all Record type 2 profiles.

[image]

Comment: Is he assigned to a sharing group? Perhaps he's not assigned to the correct group now that he's been moved to a different division.

Comment: I just checked, but he wasn't assigned to any group. I created one for his division and added him there, but the old report folders are still showing for him.

Comment: Sounds like he's still assigned to the old group in addition to the new one. Groups aren't exclusive. One can belong to many.

Comment: It only shows him belonging to one group though

Comment: Does his basic profile give him access to them? What about his personal folders or who it shows in his profile that he reports to (e.g. his previous supervisor granting viewing of a shared group's files)? Perhaps he's gaining permissions through some other means that he was given but hasn't been removed. Check to see if it shows someone reporting to him via Roles who has access. Do others in his division use the same profile? Those are just a few ideas that come to mind.